# Why i can't filter local json file in this case (vuejs2)

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

[image: it's look like this.]
Before i set vue cli-3 in my project, the filter could work. After I set it up, I cannot reach any result. What am I doing wrong? There isn't any error in the console. I'll share the codes below.

Thanks in advance.

```
<template>

  <div id="preview" class="nested">
       <div class="card-body"  v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{item.companyName}}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{item.positionName}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{item.cityName}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{item.townName}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{item.distance}}</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go!</a>
        </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      filteredFounded: [],
      founded: [],
      items: [],
      search: "",
      show: false,
      city: ""
    };
  },

 created() {
    this.$http
      .get("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cguWKZoQMO?indent=2")
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(res => {
        this.founded = res.items;
      });
  },
  methods: {
    setFounded() {
      this.filteredFounded = this.founded.filter(items => {
        return (
          items.cityName.toLowerCase() === this.city.toLowerCase() &&
          items.positionName.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
        );
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

i forgot add this code. sorry. everythings look fine but. Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined error fetch now.

```
<template>
<div id="app" class="nested">
    <div class="card w-50">
        <div class="search">
            <input type="text" class="job" v-model="search" placeholder="Job...">
            <select name="" class="city" id="">
                <option value="Seçiniz">Seçiniz</option>
                <option value="İstanbul">İstanbul</option>
                <option value="Ankara">Ankara</option>
                <option value="İzmir">İzmir</option>
                <option value="Çanakkale">Çanakkale</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="find">
            <button v:on-click="setFounded">Find!</button>
        </div>           
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where are you calling the `setFounded() ` method?

Comment: oh sorry, <div class="find">
                <button v:on-click="setFounded">Find!</button>
            </div>

Comment: ok i find your mistakes and i'm writing the full answer

Comment: edit the question and add full codes. thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not related to Vue Cli 3.x, you had done some mistakes in the promise scope such as `return res.json()` and `this.founded = res.items;` but the `res` object have the following  keys :`config` `data` `headers` `request` `status` and `statusText`.

In this situation we need only the `data` property which is an array of objects (items), **so change `return res.json()` to `return res.data`  and `this.founded = res.items;` to `this.founded = res.data;`**

add `v-model="city"` to the select as follow `<select name="" class="city" id="" v-model="city">` and you had written `v:on-click` incorrectly, change it to `@click`

Finally change `return ( items.cityName.toLowerCase() === this.city.toLowerCase() && items.positionName.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) );` **to** `return ( items.cityName === this.city && items.positionName===this.search );`

Comment: but i still doesn't show the results. when i click find button it must be show the results. bu its didnt

Comment: because the `search` and `city` are empty strings

Comment: i dont understand, what can i do now?

Comment: dude, I did the same thing what you said and i cant reach results. i think v-model not working properly. look this https://i.hizliresim.com/r1kaJa.png picture. you will understand what i say.

Comment: i can't see the picture because it returns 403 forbidden

Comment: can you see now?

Comment: it should work, but i guess the problem is ` return (
          items.cityName.toLowerCase() === this.city.toLowerCase() &&
          items.positionName.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
        );`  change it to `  return (
     items.cityName === this.city &&
          items.positionName==this.search
        );`

Comment: regrettably. this is really unbelievable. i dont understand. what is problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179695/discussion-between-boussadjra-brahim-and-omer-dogan).